# How to import data into folder that has been created in application in ios

Tags: ios

I created a folder inside my document directory.I am able to display that folder in table view.My question is how to import data into that folder which exists in myphone in ios.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I just created folder.
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSLog(@"%@:pathaaa",paths);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        _dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];

Answer (score 0):

You can't import directly as you wanted, you must ask permissions of user to access photos, videos, and music on iPhone. And you can't get any other files on iPhone except these. You can't find any file such as .doc, .xls etc., like in android

Comment: Can I use iCloud to import any kind of files into my app.

Comment: Yes you can use iCloud without any doubt, to set up icloud there is a lenghty procedure and morevore u need developer account associated with ios developer program

Comment: Can you please provide me any examples if you have any.

Comment: I do not have any, but you can find through developer library, or too many blogs are there